# Los comandos de Python no son encontrados en visual studio code

Tags: python, python-3.x, vscode, rutas, terminal

Cuando intento establecer la terminal de python me salta el siguiente mensaje, me sale realmente con todos los comandos, ya he revisado que python esté agregado al path.
[image: imagen del error]

Comment: Eso puede ocurrir si no has activado la extensión python o si no se ha cargado. Cómprúebalo en la pestaña de extensiones.

Comment: ya revisé la extensión y sigue tirando el mismo problema. :(

Comment: Sin más información es imposible saber qué te pasa, pero lo seguro es que no te funciona la extensión. Puede que sea por incompatibilidad con alguna otra extensión. Prueba a deactivar todas las extensiones y ves activando, una a una, empezando por la de python. O, mejor aún, prueba la selección de extensiones por bisección: https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect